# Can't connect to the wifi network

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

First it was note even showing the wifi icon,but I somehow searched google and it started showing the icon. I don't know whether the wifi driver was installed or not. I don't know any coding:)  I just ran `lshw -C network` and found this.

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 06
       serial: ec:a8:6b:f2:58:57
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.3
       logical name: wlx00e04c818802
       serial: 00:e0:4c:81:88:02
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1.4
       logical name: enx026d525c8ecc
       serial: 02:6d:52:5c:8e:cc
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.5 link=yes multicast=yes
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I am using realtek rtl8188eu  802.11n wifi chipset.with adnet external usb wifi adapter.
It is showing network0 DISABLED.
Is the wifi driver recognized? I am using ethernet from mobile hotspot now. Please help me I need to attend my online classes.

Comment: Read `man rfkill`. Your WiFi device (which uses the `r8188eu` driver) may be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which linux distro you use, but I am on 16.04 and the below works perfectly for Ubuntu 16.04

Steps:

cd to Downloads and then clone this repo using:
`git clone https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus`
Then

```
cd rtl8188eus
nano Makefile
```

Scroll down to the line that says

```
export TopDIR ?= $(srctree)/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8188eus
```

For me it is on the 151st line, it might not be the same for you.

Change the line to:
`export TopDIR ?= $ ~/Downloads/rtl8188eus`

Then do:

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eus
```

You might have to restart to get the wireless working.